# Press a button behind a UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview

I have a button and half of the button is covered by a UIView (for styling).

I was wondering if there was any way to make this UIView "touch transparent" as it were, so if you press on it it lets you select the image behind it?

Or will I just have to make it a button itself?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the UIView's userInteractionEnabled property to NO.

Answer (score 0):

try to make the UIView opaque to NO